# SQL Query to Return Results If All the ID's Have Matches

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables:

`COUNTRY`, with the two columns `COUNTRY_ID` and `PERSON_REGION_ID`.

`PERSON`, with many columns, in which `PERSON_REGION_ID` column is same as `COUNTRY.PERSON_REGION_ID`, and `PERSON_ID` is ID column of `PERSON`.

Query is as follows:

```
SELECT *
from COUNTRY
where PERSON_REGION_ID IN (
        SELECT PERSON_REGION_ID
        FROM PERSON
        WHERE PERSON_ID IN (111, 888)))
  AND COUNTRY_ID = 44;
```

The above query gives results if any one of the ID as matches (111 or 888).

I want the query to give results if both 111 and 888 has matches else return no results.

How this can be achieved?

Comment: I didn't understood that ... you want to return results if PersonID 111 AND PersonID 888 have countryID 44 ... and if only 1 person of those 2 got no CountryID to return null?

Comment: @Veljko89 - Yes. Exactly

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer using joins here

EDIT: To answer your comment, it depends if it's procedure or just query. But you declare variables and go with that

By the way, just for the record ... this is T-SQL, not oracle's syntax

```
declare @CountryID int -- = 44? (if for some reason you keep CountryID as type other 
                       --      then int, just change it to correct one)
declare @Person1 int -- = 111?
declare @Person2 int -- = 888?

select C.* from Country C
join Person P1 on C.Person_Region_ID = P1.PersionRegion_ID and P1.Country_ID = @CountryID
join Person P2 on C.Person_Region_ID = P2.PersionRegion_ID and P2.Country_ID = @CountryID
where P1.PersionID = @Person1 and P2.PersionID = @Person2
```

Comment: @Veljko89- Thanx. The Person ID's are dynamic. The query should work for any number of ID's. How this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `group by` with `having` in the subquery:

```
select * 
from COUNTRY 
where PERSON_REGION_ID IN (
      select PERSON_REGION_ID 
      from PERSON
      where PERSON_ID IN ( 111, 888))
      group by PERSON_REGION_ID 
      having count(PERSON_ID) = 2)
   and COUNTRY_ID= 44;
```

If there are duplicate `person_id's` per `PERSON_REGION_ID` , you'll need to use `distinct` with the `count`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use EXISTS() like this:

```
   SELECT * from COUNTRY t
   WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM PERSON s
                WHERE t.PERSON_REGION_ID = s.PERSON_REGION_ID
                     AND PERSON_ID IN ( 111, 888)
                GROUP BY PERSON_REGION_ID
                HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT PERSON_ID) = 2)
       AND COUNTRY_ID = 44
```

Comment: (DISTINCT PERSON_ID) = 2) . The =2 part can be done dynamically? The PERSION_ID's are dynamic in numbers